# When does Gmail display images automatically?

Tags: gmail, privacy

Google [claims](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126) that inline images in authenticated email are shown automatically in Gmail. Yet I do not observe this with transactional mail I get from serious organizations, such as Stack Exchange and MailChimp: the images are hidden by default and the “Display images below” link appears. `Authentication-Results` says `spf=pass`, `dkim=pass`; DKIM key length is 1024.

Is the information in Gmail’s help outdated, or do they have some extra rules?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got it. They mean images attached to the message with `Content-Disposition: inline`. This does not apply to remote images.